# How to force deletion of corrupt ArcSDE Raster?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

ArcSDE 9.3 / ArcGIS Server 10.0 / ArcCatalog Advanced 10.0

After an unsuccessful attempt at creating a mosiac, ArcCatalog refuses to allow deletion of the corrupt Raster file.

The Mosiac creation was corrupted because of lack of file space on the MS SQL Server. Now I cannot open the file or delete it.

Is there any way I can force delete the Raster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [ArcSDE command line tool](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcsde/9.1/admin_cmd_refs/sderaster.htm) `sderaster` to delete and drop the raster layer.

These tools often attempt to clean up corrupt layers where ArcCatalog fails, and are installed with ArcSDE so can likely found on your database server or where you have ran the ArcSDE setup.

Alternatively if that doesn't work another more risky solution is to manually drop the tables for the raster layer, and remove the metadata for the raster from the [SDE system tables](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../002q/002q00000080000000.htm). I wouldn't recommend this unless you are pretty comfortable with ArcSDE as you can easily mess up your instance.